# Netbeans can't find running Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans

I'm running Tomcat inside of Netbeans. I added Tomcat server(not bundled with Netbeans) to Servers in Netbeans. But, when i'm trying to run Tomcat, it starts(i can visit Tomcat home page), but Netbeans can't find it running. Where is the problem?

No stacktrace in Tomcat.
When i'm deploying my project`s war in this Tomcat manually, everything works, but i need to deploy it automatically from Netbeans.

Configuration:
Netbeans 6.8 + Tomcat 6.0.26 + JSF and Hibernate project.

Comment: Are you running it in windows?

Answer (score 0):

I changed port from 8080 to 8081, and it seems to work. I don't have another Tomcat running on background. Smth is using this port, and i don't know why.

Comment: You can use `netstat -a -b` to find out what process has a particular port open.

Comment: Yes, i tried to use it. I even saw, that, when i'm closing netbeans, this port is free. So, i think netbeans is using it, but for what purposes?